# Undefined function 'insertShape' for input arguments of type 'uint8'

Tags: matlab

I'm facing this error when running my function in matlab

```
"Undefined function 'insertShape' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
Error in rubberSheetNormalisation (line 117)
       img = insertShape(img, 'circle', [yrt(:),xrt(:),2*ones(size(xrt(:)))],'Color','r');"
```

This is the function that called in line 117:

```
if debug img = insertShape(img, 'circle', [yrt(:),xrt(:),2*ones(size(xrt(:)))],'Color','r');
img = insertShape(img, 'circle', [ylt(:),xlt(:),2*ones(size(xrt(:)))],'Color','blue');
```

I don't know what the problem is; I passed rgb unit8 image to this function. I convert it to gray but still the same error appears.

Comment: matlab could be case sensitive for this. Have you tried 'Circle' instead of 'circle'?

Comment: Do you have computer vision system toolbox installed?

Comment: What does `which insertShape` return? Do you have the function?

Comment: yes, now I tried 'Circle' but problem is still

Comment: insertShape is a built-in function in matlab,it should be found because I have computer vision toolbox

Comment: What version of MATLAB are/were you running this in? [`insertShape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html) wasn't added to the Computer Vision Toolbox until R2014a.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the add-on "Computer Vision System Toolbox".

Check the folliowing link for how to install a new add-on:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/manage-your-add-ons.html